# React native: what is the difference between opening an external URL in-app and launching the native browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, browser

I am using React native to develop a mobile application, and an external module's function I use to provide the user login flow via an identity provider, opens the link to the sign-in flow *in-app*, like shown in the header below.

[image: in application web browser]

The sign out functionality offered by this module is documented to be obsolete, so I am implementing my own routing to the identity provider using Linking from the react-native node module, except this actually opens my **native web browser** rather than showing the page in-app (and subsequently fails to redirect back to my app).

My question is, what is the technical *difference* between an app opening a link in-app like shown above, and the app simply launching the native browser, such as chrome? And would this affect functionality like redirecting back to the initial application once the user process has been fulfilled (my guess is that it should not affect it).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an 'in app browser'. I'm not sure if React Native has anything built in to support this, but I know that there are packages which do, e.g. https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the difference is that the in-app browser on IOS is an instance of 
[sfsafariviewcontroller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) and on Android, is an instance of [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).